# Variables that accept values with pipe | as separator

Tags: c#, .net

I have six variables of type `String`, they contain 0/1 value retrieved from a DB field bit.

So,these variables are value of radio boxes, that have Y=1 | N=0.

Now,  I have a Varilable,  that accept one or more enumerator values, they are separated by pipe "|".

```
if (bool.Parse(mht_ReadAccess) && bool.Parse(mht_WriteAccess))
{
  var grantAccessRequest = new GrantAccessRequest
  {
    PrincipalAccess = new PrincipalAccess
    {
      AccessMask = AccessRights.WriteAccess | AccessRights.ReadAccess,
      Principal = userreference
    },
    Target = recordentityreference
  };
}
```

Now, this is a static way to solve this problem.  If I have 6 variables like "mht_WriteAccess" , how can I check how many of them are set on  true, and automatically change the situation for the "AccessMask" variable, and so pass all the right enum values with pipe.

I want to know if there's a way to do this automatically, maybe with any cycle?

Comment: It's bitwise OR `1 | 2 | 4 = 7 => 00X | 0X0 | X00 = XXX`

Comment: Are you sure all these tags are related to question?

Comment: What exactly is this Java or C#?

Comment: As an aside, in C#, `bool.Parse` won't accept values like "1" or "0" only "true" or "false" (however, case is ignored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AccessRights rights = 0;

if (bool.Parse(mht_ReadAccess))
    rights |= AccessRights.ReadAccess;

if (bool.Parse(mht_WriteAccess))
    rights |= AccessRights.WriteAccess;

// do the same for all other variables

var grantAccessRequest = new GrantAccessRequest
{
    PrincipalAccess = new PrincipalAccess
    {
        AccessMask = rights,
        Principal = userreference
    },
    Target = recordentityreference
};
```